# List of all reserved keywords in django templates?

Tags: python, django, keyword

I need a list of all the reserved keywords used by django's templating engine. Most of these keywords can be found here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/

Is there a programmatic way of getting just a list of the keywords? Or a document that contains all of them in list format?

Comment: Those aren't "reserved keywords", they're just tags and filters provided by Django itself.

Comment: I have created a pastebin of the output from dandonovan's (slightly modified) program: http://pastebin.com/82CyecW2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The django filters and tags are defined in the documentation at the link you provide - and that documented is created (using sphinx I think) automatically from the code `defaultfilters.py` code that Stefano suggests.

If it helps, then looking at the `admindocs` ([admindocs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/)) app will give you an even more accurate description as it will also include any custom tags and filters that you have defined.

```
from django.contrib.admindocs.views import load_all_installed_template_libraries
from django import template

app_libs = template.libraries.items()
builtin_libs = [(None, lib) for lib in template.builtins]

for module_name, library in builtin_libs + app_libs:
    for tag_name, tag_func in library.tags.items():
        print 'Tag: ', tag_name
    for filter_name, filter_func in library.filters.items():
        print 'Filter: ', filter_name
```

You have to run this from `django-admin.py shell` or `python manage.py shell`

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you mean by a "list" ?

1. You can extract it by copy pasting from the doc page you link;
2. You can extract it with JS from that same page, eg:

   `document.querySelectorAll('a[href="#built-in-tag-reference"] ~ ul > li > a')`

   will get you all the tag elements; you can pick it from there.
3. Or you can use the python code from django;

default template tags & filters are under:

```
/django/templates/defaultfilters.py
/django/templates/defaulttags.py
```

If you could better explain what you objective is, you might get more relevant answers; in any case, I think starting from the django python code should get you closer to the result you want.

Additional filters and tags are loaded with the {% load TAG %} tag. It's interesting to see how the loading works, because you can actually easy hack it and substitute default filters/tags with your own if you really want.

Comment: My objective is to get the keywords as I am writing a syntax colorer/highlighter for [SHPAML](http://shpaml.webfactional.com/) and django for the [colorer](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/) eclipse plugin. I need the list of reserved keywords for django so that I can highlight those reserved words inside django template tags {% %}.

Comment: @EricGustavson in this case, any of these methods should work and be similarly quick... you are only needing a static list of filters and tags - or use danodonovan code that basically starts from my suggestion #3!